# Structural shifts

Tags: r, cointegration, ranks

I am using the R programming language to analyze the cointegration of 5 data sets. I have determined that the series share 3 cointegrating vectors after taking structural shifts into account following the approach of Lutkepohl et al (2004).

My questions are:

1. How can I incorporate the 3 vectors into the full matrix form of the final VECM?
2. How do I code in R the estimation of a VECM with a shift dummy variable to capture the break detected by the Lutkepohl et al (2004) test, i.e., is it possible to include a shift dummy in a VECM? If so, can you please help me with a code example,
   e.g., say the five data sets are `a b c d e`, cointegration rank `r=3` and break date `1975Q1`.

Any references would also be very much appreciated.